# How to force `cdk deploy` even if an earlier deployed resource is not found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

We have a stack where one of the resources (a container) was stuck and we had to manually delete that resource from ECS.

Now the command `cdk deploy`, always rolls back with following error,

> Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::ECS::Service' with identifier 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1::service/cdkStackCluster/MyCdkStack-myService1Service54FA7D70-ax55DVPOJUIj' was not found." (RequestToken: XXXXXXXX-7251-339f-21dd-f89a94b916d1, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

Is there a way to tell CDK to ignore this error and move ahead?

Comment: Related (bad news): https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16769. Perhaps you could investigate removing the resource from your CDK app, re-deploy, then re-add the resource. Alternatively, manually create the resource, [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) it into the relevant stack that CDK created, then re-deploy. I'm not confident in either approach as I haven't done this so caveat emptor.

Comment: Alternative method to @jarmod. Depending on what the stack is, you could destroy it and redeploy, that should fix ot but will destroy the whole stack and leave a bunch of orphaned resources if they have a retain deletion policy. You could also remove the ECR service from your code and then deploy it; after the deployment is successfull you can add it back in and deploy the whole stack again.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I tried your suggestion and it worked. Removed resource from CDK app and deployed. Then re-added the resource and deployed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the suggestion given by @jarmod and @TrygviLaksafoss.

Basically, I removed the part of CDK code that created the ECS service which was manually deleted. And deployed (`cdk deploy`). This cleaned up the component which was causing the problem.

Then I restored the code which was removed in the previous step and deployed again. This restored all the services as expected.